# Issue copying source code to IFS as text, mapping error

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

so I have an issue with copying source code to IFS. I basically just want the text from the code to look like a .txt file. I'm storing on a local machine to keep another backup on top of the ones already there.

I found and worked with a CL program that works beautifully for many of the files I want. Here is what it does:

```
PGM        PARM(&file &LIBRARY)
             dcl        &file  *char 10
             dcl        &library *char 12
             dcl        &docname *char 12
             DCLF       FILE(QTEMP/MEMBERS)

             monmsg     cpf0000

             DSPFD      FILE(&LIBRARY/&FILE) TYPE(*MBRLIST) +
                          OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILE(QTEMP/MEMBERS)


 Loop:       Rcvf
             MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0864) EXEC(GOTO CMDLBL(EXIT))


             CPYTOIMPF  FROMFILE(&LIBRARY/&FILE &MLNAME) +
                          TOSTMF('/BACKUP/SOURCE/' *TCAT &LIBRARY +
                          *TCAT '/' *TCAT &FILE *TCAT '/' *TCAT +
                          &MLNAME) MBROPT(*REPLACE) +
                          STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII) RCDDLM(*CRLF) +
                          DTAFMT(*FIXED)


             goto       loop


     Exit:
             RCLRSC
             ENDPGM
```

Again, this works for several of my libraries and also files. However I have some that give me a data mapping error and will just keep giving me a notice that it's being wrapped until I end the job. Also other files in the same library "work" where it transfers data however the text is not readable so basically worthless. It's only this one library that I have encountered this issue.

I've looked for references but all the info I found wasn't specific enough to my situation.

Any idea why these dspf, pf, rpgle, clp, txt, etc... items are different. Another thing I get when I run it is:

```
Primary group of object QCPEXTEMPS in QTEMP type *USRSPC changed.
Primary group of object QACP000135 in QTEMP type *USRSPC changed.
Primary group of object QACEXFLD12 in QTEMP type *USRSPC changed.
```

I don't know if this is what I get when successful, I don't look at the code when it is successful. I don't know if this matters either. But in my job log it shows just before the error.

```
Data mapping error on member
Data mapping error on member
Data mapping error on member
Data mapping error on member
```

If I F1 on "data mapping error on member xxxx" I get this

```
Cause . . . . . :   A data mapping error occurred on field                    
  file_member_1.SRCDAT in record number 1, record format *FIRST, member   
  number 1, in member xxxx file xxxx in library xxxx, because of 
  error
  code 1. The error code meanings follow:                                     
    1 -- There is data in a decimal field that is not valid.
```

That doesn't make sense to me because I thought I was just basically "copy" "paste" into a text file on the IFS.

Comment: Have you looked at the data in file_member_1.SRCDAT in the first record? The error here is telling you that data is bad.  It's quite possible you have a null or something in the table that the conversion can't process.

Comment: Yes It's just like a spacer line:

A*******************************************************************

Comment: OK but the error message says that it thinks this is a decimal field.  If what you said is true, it looks like you have text in a field that is supposed to be a number.

Comment: Which doesn't make sense, it's a dspf. The A spec is first. What would cause it to need it be a number? I've never seen a dspf with a number before an A.

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you tried removing the spacer line to see if that fixes the issue?  Also, do you maybe have hidden color bits in column 5 as well?

Comment: It's multiple files that this occurs with, and there are over 4k+ members in the file, I don't want to go through every file affected and get rid of the first line. Also what are hidden color bits ? I don't have anything in column 5 it's all blank.

Comment: I understand that.  It'd be good to confirm that it is that exact line that is causing problems though.

Comment: No change. Still gives the same error even after deleting that first line.

Comment: Source physical files all have three fields: SRCSEQ, SRCDAT, and SRCDTA, in that order. SRCSEQ is the line number, SRCDAT is the date, and SRCDTA is the text. The first two fields are numeric, and each is 6 bytes long. That should give you a clue.

Comment: Those first fields are populated with .20  .30  .40....etc. Other files use  1.00  2.00  3.00. Not sure how it's invalid, it's a 6  2   field. So the .20  should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using CPYTOIMPF with invalid data in the SRCSEQ and SRCDAT fields, and I got that error.

But CPYTOSTMF worked fine, and it seems to produce the same result for a source file.

Comment: Tried this, this morning and had an issue. I created .savf  which isn't what  I wanted to do but spending too much time on this. I may try to revisit this suggestion and play with it more.

Comment: What was the CPYTOSTMF command that you used? I have never seen it create a savf

Comment: No the command CPYTOSTMF didn't create a savf, I mean as my work around I created a savf of the members instead of copying the text. So if I want that info again I'd have to do a restore. 

    CPYTOSTMF  FROMMBR('/QSYS.LIB/' *TCAT &LIBRARY *TCAT '.LIB/' +
                          *TCAT &FILE *TCAT '.FILE/' *TCAT &MLNAME *TCAT +
                          '.MBR') TOSTMF('/BACKUP/SOURCE/' *TCAT &LIBRARY +
                          *TCAT '/' *TCAT &FILE *TCAT '/' *TCAT &MLNAME) +
                          STMFOPT(*REPLACE) STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII)